# Why using Federation Provider?

Tags: asp.net-identity, wif, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

That what I understand so far:-

A user login into IDP, then IDP provides a token to that user, when user tries to access an application that trust IDP, the application will validate the token to authorize user to do certain things based on provided claims.

Application trust IDP X = Application registers at the IDP in order to receive X tokens.

Federation Provider is used for what?? one explanation I got, is that FP is used when two organizations are not trusting each other and still need employees to use SSO to access both organizations networks.  Why they don't simply trust each other instead of using FP?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to abbreviate federated authentication but the main concepts are these :
- The STS is the thing to do authentication so no application has to deal with passwords anymore.  Security wise there is only one place to harden.
- In general each relying party gets its own security token.  The STS will issue the tokens.  In general it automatically issues a token once a user was logged in to any application.  This provides single sign on.  SInce the "cookie" to keep you signed in is in the STS domain this works.
- Similarily, when a user signs out, she is automatically signed out to all applications using single signout.
So the main thing is that you can connect any application you want.  That application will never see the credentials of the users (since only your own STS sees them).  This is a secure way to create an eco system of applications to which your users will have access.
Another benefit are the claims that usually stored in the security token.  These are properties for the user that any relying party will automatically get.  Without such mechanism you would need to create some kind of API where the Relying party could query this information which is both less secure and more cumbersome.  Also, the expiry of the security token makes sure that any application that has non up-to-date data (such as an email that was changed) will get the upt to date data either when the user logss off and logs on again or when the security token expires (which is a compromise you have to make.)

Answer (score 0):

Per @paullem

"In the WIF/Microsoft world "Identity Provider" (IP or IdP) is the term for a server that authenticates a user (the server is connected to some account database, AD in the current case of ADFS).

Federation server/provider is often used for a server that receives a SAML Token from another server. And then forwards it to the next Relying Party.

An ADFS server is often / typically *both*."

So typically they are one and the same.

Can't recall ever doing an installation of an IDP that was just a federation provider.